# Looping through a queue with for loops and If / Else

Tags: javascript, loops, queue

Hi and thanks for taking the time to look at this.

I'm trying to achieve the following output:

```
Iteration 0:
Queue 1 = 2345678910 | Queue 2 =
Iteration 1:
Queue 1 = 3579       | Queue 2 = 2
Iteration 2:
Queue 1 = 57         | Queue 2 = 23
Iteration 3:
Queue 1 = 7          | Queue 2 = 235
Iteration 4:
Queue 1 =            | Queue 2 = 2357
```

This is supposed to be an implementation of "[The Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)"
I won't lie this is obviously school work! (Though the deadline has past and I'm not trying to get an easy grade. I actually want to know why I couldn't get this to work)
I did search intensively but all similar things I found are implemented using arrays.(which the professor doesn't allow)

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/qriz75/6v7k4z0v/) is a fiddle that shows where I'm at:

This seems to be my problem It won't remove the last item.

```
if (this.first == this.last) {
  this.first = null;
  return this.first.content;
  this.length--;
}
```

I cluttered it up with all kinds of control statements to find the logic problem ...

when I started I was pretty sure I can do it like follows:

Loop through Queue 1 and save current value to (x) 
-- Loop through Queue 1, move the first item to Queue 2 
---- IF/Else current item is divisible by x move on else re-queue

I switched it up to while loops but it gets stuck with the removal of the last item

```
// find the primes function
function fp() {
  fillQueue(); // call the fillQueue function below

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "Ctrl " + "|it. " + it + " |queue length " + q1.length + " |x " + x + " |current x" + cx + " |Q1: = " + q1.toString() + " | Q2: = " + q2.toString() + " | Q3: = " + q3.toString() + "<br />";

  while (q1.length >= 0) {
    dq1();
    cx = x;
    q3.enqueue(cx);

    while (q1.length >= 0) {
      dq1();
      eval();
      it++;
    }

    while (q2.length >= 0) {
      dq2();
      d1.enqueue(x);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Remember: `=` is assignment, `==` (or better, `===`) is for comparison. This line is going to cause you some trouble `it = n - 1`. That should also probably be `<` or `<=` instead of `=`.

Comment: thanks for the reply ... that fixed the iteration problem and got me closer ... still have some issues to work out as the output still isn't right

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a different approach and loop while the first element of numbers is smaller than the number until the check should take place. Make the protocol output, push the first element of numbers to `multiples`, then filter `numbers` with a check for the multiple of number at index zero.

At the end make another protocol output.

```js
function calculate() {
    var number = document.getElementById('number').value,
        numbers = Array.apply(null, { length: number - 1 }).map(function (_, i) { return i + 2; }),
        multiples = [];

    while (numbers[0] < number) {
        document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += numbers.join(' ') + ' ||| ' + multiples.join(' ') + '\n';
        multiples.push(numbers[0]);    
        numbers = numbers.filter(function (a) {
            return a % numbers[0];
        });    
    }
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += numbers.join(' ') + ' ||| ' + multiples.join(' ') + '\n';
}
```

```html
<input id="number" /><button onclick="calculate()">calculate</button>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ... I like that ...  the professor doesn't allow the use of arrays. I'm going to try to implement this with queues.

Comment: something isn't right with my de-queue process ... It won't remove the last item ;-(